# In FeedMe transform one data element before it gets parsed

Tags: plugin-feedme

I've got a json data feed that has related entry titles in a pipe delimited format like so:

`'Entry1 | Entry2 | Entry3'`

I thought feedme actually used to be ok with that, but it looks like now it has to be an array.

So i'm trying to hook into a FeedMe event and transform that data into an array before FeedMe then parses it.

```
Event::on(Fields::class, Fields::EVENT_BEFORE_PARSE_FIELD, function(FieldEvent $event) {
            $value = $event->parsedValue;
            if ($event->feed['id'] == 1) {
                if ($event->fieldHandle === 'category') {
                    $newValue = array_map('trim', explode('|', $value));
                    $event->parsedValue = $newValue;
                }
            }
        });
```

This doesn't seem to be having any effect though, what am I missing?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to use the `Fields::EVENT_BEFORE_PARSE_FIELD` event here - that's too late in the process to do what you need. Instead you should fix the property in your input data that you want to map to categories, by preprocessing it into an array. The easiest way to do this in Feed Me is with a [custom Data Type](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/developers/data-types.html).

All we need to do in this case is extend Feed Me's built-in JSON Data Type and loop over the items in the feed to post process them:

```php
<?php

namespace modules\datatypes;

use craft\feedme\datatypes\Json;
use illuminate\Support\Collection;

class CustomJsonDatatype extends Json
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    // This will be the name of the Feed Type visible when setting up the feed
    public static string $name = 'Custom JSON';
    
    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getFeed($url, $settings, bool $usePrimaryElement = true): array
    {
        // Get the feed from the parent class
        $feed = parent::getFeed($url, $settings, $usePrimaryElement);

        // Map over the data key with our custom transformer method
        $feed['data'] = collect($feed['data'])
            ->map(function($item) {
                return $this->transformItem(collect($item));
            })
            ->toArray();
        return $feed;
    }
    
    public function transformItem(Collection $item): ?Collection
    {
        // do whatever you want here to each item - the below is untested but _should_ work
        if ($item->Category) {
            $values = collect(explode('|', $item->Category));
            $item->put('Category', $values->map(fn($value) => trim($value))->toArray());
        }
        
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Then in a custom module register your Data Type with Feed Me:

```php
<?php

namespace modules;

use Craft;
use craft\feedme\events\RegisterFeedMeDataTypesEvent;
use craft\feedme\services\DataTypes;
use modules\datatypes\CustomJsonDatatype;
use yii\base\Event;
use yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

class Module extends BaseModule
{
    public function init(): void
    {
        Craft::setAlias('@modules', __DIR__);

        parent::init();

        Craft::$app->onInit(function() {
            $this->registerFeedMeDataTypes();
        });
    }
    
    private function registerFeedMeDataTypes(): void
    {
        // see https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/developers/data-types.html#the-registerfeedmedatatypes-event
        Event::on(
            DataTypes::class,
            DataTypes::EVENT_REGISTER_FEED_ME_DATA_TYPES,
            static function(RegisterFeedMeDataTypesEvent $e) {
                $e->dataTypes[] = CustomJsonDatatype::class;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Tom Davies, this seems like a very good answer from a very wise man.

Comment: You forgot "handsome"